# How do I prevent the page from scrolling when showing a dynamically created toast, using bootstrap 4's toast component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm creating toast elements dynamically using JavaScript, based on `onClick` events. That part works fine, but the problem is that the page is scrolling to the top every time I show a new toast. I am using using [Bootstrap 4's toast component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/).

Here's the container I have for showing the toast:

```html
<div id="toastDrawer" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999999;"></div>
```

(I've also tried styling with `position: fixed;` as well, and I get the same problem.

The toast I use looks something like this:

```html
<div class="toast ml-auto" id="${toastID}" role="alert" data-delay="1400" data-autohide="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="mr-auto">Success</strong>
        <small class="text-muted">${formattedTime}</small>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        Complete
    </div>
</div>
```

I then show the toast, and remove it from the DOM afterwards using the following JavaScript code:

```js
const toast = $.parseHTML(html);
$('#toastDrawer').append(toast);
const $toast = $(`#${toastID}`);
$toast.on('hidden.bs.toast', function () {
    $toast.remove();
});
$toast.toast('show');
```

I should also note that I do initialize the toast function on window load like this:

```js
$().toast();
```

Here is what the code in its entirety looks like:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    const showToast = function(event) {
      const toastID = generateID();

      const html = `\t<div class="toast ml-auto" id="${toastID}" role="alert" data-delay="1400" data-autohide="true">
\t\t<div class="toast-header">
\t\t\t<strong class="mr-auto">Success</strong>
\t\t\t<small class="text-muted">time</small>
\t\t\t<button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
\t\t\t\t<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
\t\t\t</button>
\t\t</div>
\t\t<div class="toast-body">
\t\t\tComplete
\t\t</div>
\t</div>`;
      const toast = $.parseHTML(html);
      $('#toastDrawer').append(toast);
      const $toast = $(`#${toastID}`);
      $toast.on('hidden.bs.toast', function() {
        $toast.remove();
      });
      $toast.toast('show');
    }

    $(`#testBtn`).on("click", showToast);

    const generateID = function() {
      const possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      const randomID = Array(8).join().split(',').map(function() {
        return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      }).join('');
      // Add timestamp to the random value to ensure consistently unique
      // values over time
      return String(randomID + Date.now());
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="toastDrawer" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999999;"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Toast button on bottom of page</h1>
        <h2>Filler content to make page long</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer
          malesuada. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec
          pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis. Sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Eget
          lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Quam elementum
          pulvinar etiam non quam. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum. Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar
          neque laoreet. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium viverra. Sed arcu non odio euismod. Maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit
          amet mattis vulputate enim. Nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Habitasse
          platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat
          blandit aliquam etiam erat velit. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies
          mi eget. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium
          quam vulputate dignissim. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis.
          Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet. Mauris a diam maecenas sed. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="testBtn" href="#">Create Toast</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
  </div>
  <!--container-->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Every time I show a new toast, the page scrolls to the top. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out the page was always scrolling to the top because I had been clicking an anchor element with a link to `#` (i.e. `<a href="#">...</a>`). So, I simply added the following to the top of the function for displaying the toast element, so it prevented the default action when a user clicks on a link:

```js
const showToast = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

That worked. Sorry if you had to read through the long question above, I just wanted to be as detailed as possible to figure this out.

‍♂️

---

Another note to anyone else who may be struggling with bootstrap toasts - change the position of the container to be `fixed`, in order to scroll with the viewport.

```html
<div id="toastDrawer" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999999;"></div>
```

The above code will keep it in the top right-hand corner of the viewport/screen, no matter where the user scrolls. Just make sure to append/add your toasts into the above toast "drawer".

I could not find this written clearly anywhere else (for those of us who are not well-versed in CSS).